# Problem iniitializing typedef struct in C (Iseries /AS400)

Tags: c, ibm-midrange

What I'm doing wrong when I'm trying to initialize this typedef struct.

I did the same declaration in linux and I could create perfect.

This is the definition:

```
typedef struct {                                                               
 char mask;    /* char data will be bitwise AND with this */                   
 char lead;    /* start bytes of current char in utf-8 encoded character */    
 uint32_t beg; /* beginning of codepoint range */                              
 uint32_t end; /* end of codepoint range */                                    
 int bits_stored; /* the number of bits from the codepoint that fits in char */
}utf_t;                                                                        
utf_t * utf[];                                                                 
/*                 mask        lead        beg      end       bits  */         
 utf_t * utf[] = {                                                           
    [0] = &(utf_t){0b00111111, 0b10000000, 0,       0,        6    },          
    [1] = &(utf_t){0b01111111, 0b00000000, 0000,    0177,     7    },          
    [2] = &(utf_t){0b00011111, 0b11000000, 0200,    03777,    5    },          
    [3] = &(utf_t){0b00001111, 0b11100000, 04000,   0177777,  4    },          
    [4] = &(utf_t){0b00000111, 0b11110000, 0200000, 04177777, 3    },          
          &(utf_t){0},                                                         
   };
```

When I try to compile, iy don't create the spoolfile, but in the joblog shows this message:

```
Message ID . . . . . . :   MCH3601       Severity . . . . . . . :   40       
Message type . . . . . :   Escape                                            
Date sent  . . . . . . :   18/11/19      Time sent  . . . . . . :   10:02:49 

Message . . . . :   Pointer not set for location referenced.                 
Cause . . . . . :   A pointer was used, either directly or as a basing       
  pointer, that has not been set to an address.
```

Could someone tell me what I'm doing wrong?
Thank you.

Regards,

Comment: When and where do you do the initialization of the array? If inside a function the compound objects you create will be temporary and pointers to them will be invalid once the block ends.

Comment: To which standard of C is your compiler conforming?

Comment: 1st comment: I declare this typedef struct afert the definition of #include's pgm. It's not inside any function, it's a global definition.
2nd. comment: I don't know but I think it's an ANSI C

Comment: Do you really need an array of pointers? Why not an array of structure objects instead? Then if you need a pointer to the structure use the address-of operator.

Comment: Sorry, perhaps I should start begining from here because I'm trying to use this code https://rosettacode.org/wiki/UTF-8_encode_and_decode#C --> this code works in Linux RHEL but in the Iseries it fails on the definition this typedef struct. Sorry, maybe I didn't reply your comment, but I'm new in C and I'm a little lost.

Comment: it is not ANSI C as you use compound literals

Comment: ANSI C does not have binary prefix `0b`

Comment: I can find nothing wrong with this code, apart from the non-standard binary numbers. It is fishy code sure, but valid as far as I can tell. I suspect that the error is elsewhere.

Comment: so, then how shoul I write this binary codes?

Comment: The IBM i C/C++ compiler supports C89, C99, C++98, Standard C++ and some of C++11. If you need the ISO numbers for these, look [here](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_ibm_i_74/rzarg/about_this_reference.htm)

Answer (score 1):

According to the documentation [here](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_ibm_i_74/rzarg/ic.htm), there are no binary integer literals recognized by the IBM i C/C++ compiler. In fact, if I try to compile your code snippet, it fails on the binary literals. But If I exchange the binary literals for hex literals, it works:

```
#include <stdint.h>

typedef struct {
 char mask;    /* char data will be bitwise AND with this */
 char lead;    /* start bytes of current char in utf-8 encoded character */
 uint32_t beg; /* beginning of codepoint range */
 uint32_t end; /* end of codepoint range */
 int bits_stored; /* the number of bits from the codepoint that fits in char */
}utf_t;
utf_t * utf[];
/*                 mask  lead  beg      end       bits  */
 utf_t * utf[] = {
    [0] = &(utf_t){0x3f, 0x80, 0,       0,        6    },
    [1] = &(utf_t){0x7f, 0x00, 0000,    0177,     7    },
    [2] = &(utf_t){0x1f, 0xc0, 0200,    03777,    5    },
    [3] = &(utf_t){0x0f, 0xe0, 04000,   0177777,  4    },
    [4] = &(utf_t){0x07, 0xf0, 0200000, 04177777, 3    },
          &(utf_t){0},
   };
```

Comment: Please don't change my answer to something different.

Answer (score 0):

you use the compound literals here:

two ways of initialization:

```
utf_t *utf[6];  
utf_t *utf1[] = {                                                           
    &(utf_t){0b00111111, 0b10000000, 0,       0,        6    },          
    &(utf_t){0b01111111, 0b00000000, 0000,    0177,     7    },          
    &(utf_t){0b00011111, 0b11000000, 0200,    03777,    5    },          
    &(utf_t){0b00001111, 0b11100000, 04000,   0177777,  4    },          
    &(utf_t){0b00000111, 0b11110000, 0200000, 04177777, 3    },          
    &(utf_t){0},                                                         
   };                                                               

void foo(void)
{

memcpy(utf, (utf_t *[]){                                                           
    &(utf_t){0b00111111, 0b10000000, 0,       0,        6    },          
    &(utf_t){0b01111111, 0b00000000, 0000,    0177,     7    },          
    &(utf_t){0b00011111, 0b11000000, 0200,    03777,    5    },          
    &(utf_t){0b00001111, 0b11100000, 04000,   0177777,  4    },          
    &(utf_t){0b00000111, 0b11110000, 0200000, 04177777, 3    },          
    &(utf_t){0},                                                         
   }, sizeof(utf));
}

int main()
{
    int arr[1000];
    foo();
    memset(arr,0, sizeof(arr));
    printf("%hhu %hhu %u\n", utf[2] -> mask, utf[2] -> lead, utf[2] -> beg);
    printf("%hhu %hhu %u", utf1[2] -> mask, utf1[2] -> lead, utf1[2] -> beg);
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/CegYGb

Comment: This doesn't explain why the original code didn't work though. If their compiler supports compound literals, it will support designated initializers as well.